# Perl scope function strange-ness?

Tags: perl, function, scope

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => qw ( all );

my ( $func, @list, $num );

$func = sub {
    print $num // "undef"; print "\n";
};

@list = ( 1,2,3 );

foreach $num ( @list ) {
    $func->();
};
```

This piece of perl prints

```
undef
undef 
undef
```

instead of

```
1
2
3
```

The `$func` routine can see `@list`, so why not `$num`?

Answer (score 4):

Because `foreach` loops implicitly localise their iterator variables.

See: [`perlsyn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops)

> The foreach loop iterates over a normal list value and sets the variable VAR to be each element of the list in turn. If the variable is preceded with the keyword my, then it is lexically scoped, and is therefore visible only within the loop. Otherwise, the variable is implicitly local to the loop and regains its former value upon exiting the loop. If the variable was previously declared with my, it uses that variable instead of the global one, but it's still localized to the loop. This implicit localization occurs only in a foreach loop.

But really - this doesn't come up often, because it's really bad form to do any sort of messing around with a loop iterator from outside. Narrow down your scope, and pass variables around to avoid bugs and troubleshooting pain.

Comment: I think that's badly stated.It doesn't appear to be the case that anything "*regains* its former value upon exiting the loop", instead it just seems that the wider-scoped variable becomes *visible* again. It simply seems to be a case of what's known elsewhere as a "shadowed" variable. If you take references to the inner and outer variable, you will see that those values exist *simultaneously*.

Instead it should simply say that the loop variable is implicitly taken as local to that scope, and hides any variable with the same name outside of the loop.

Comment: Perhaps true. It's more or less doing the same as `local` does, even if that isn't really clear what's going on.

Comment: @Axeman, The issue is that "variable" can refer to the name or to the scalar itself. Captures capture the scalar itself, and foreach loops change the scalar with which the name is associated. If it was a package variable, then you wouldn't have a problem, since closures don't capture package variable. They are looked up by name.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing a localized version of the `$num` variable, like Sobrique says. What you intended was to use a reference to the variable `$num`. Which is what I show here:

```
my ( $func, @list, $num );
$func = sub {
    print $$num // "undef"; print "\n";
};

@list = ( 1,2,3 );

foreach ( @list ) {
    $num = \$_;
    $func->();
};
```

You can also use the global version of the variable, instead of the lexical:

```
my ( $func, @list, $num );

$func = sub {
    print $main::num // "undef"; print "\n";
};

@list = ( 1,2,3 );

foreach $main::num ( @list ) {
    $func->();
};
```

But this is a silly way to encapsulate this. You should not use global variables inside subroutines. This is not good practice. Instead, pass the value to the sub and access it via the `@_` variable (in this case by the first array index `$_[0]`):

```
my $func = sub {
    print $_[0] // "undef"; print "\n";
};

my @list = ( 1,2,3 );

for ( @list ) {
    $func->($_);
};
```

I also fixed some idiomatic coding style above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, guess the reason is this, from the docs:

> The foreach loop iterates over a normal list value and sets the
>   variable VAR to be each element of the list in turn. If the variable
>   is preceded with the keyword my, then it is lexically scoped, and is
>   therefore visible only within the loop. Otherwise, the variable is
>   implicitly local to the loop and regains its former value upon exiting
>   the loop. If the variable was previously declared with my, it uses
>   that variable instead of the global one, but it's still localized to
>   the loop. This implicit localization occurs only in a foreach loop.

which means I should not use the foreach loop i guess, but for or while ..

Comment: No, instead you should constrain your variable scope, and _not_ reuse `$num` in separate segments of your code. Just pass it explicity.

Comment: No, this is almost never the case. If you're passing a lot of arguments, then it's entirely acceptable to pass a hash, object or array - by value or by reference - but it's really bad style to have any sort of 'action-at-a-distance'. (And that doesn't apply for loop iterators anyway).

Comment: Yea, i will make certain to at least pass what is being changed by loops. I rarely use this forum, but marvellous how quickly good replies show up, I thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I could quote perlsyn, but perlsyn does not appear to say clearly what is the case. The variable is not "localized", and there is nothing that "regains" its value upon exiting the loop. The outer variable is *hidden* when you declare the loop variable, and visible after you're out of the loop.

It implicitly *hides* the variable in the outer scope, which *retains* its value.

The output from this code scrap will illustrate:

```
use 5.022;
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => qw ( all );
use Data::Dumper;

my ( $func, @list, $num );

$func = sub {
    print $num // "undef"; print "\n";
};
$num = 101;
$func->();

my $np = \$num;
print Data::Dumper->Dump( [ $np ], [ '*np' ] );

@list = ( 1,2,3 );

foreach $num ( @list ) {
    print Data::Dumper->Dump( [ $num ], [ '*num' ] );
    print Data::Dumper->Dump( [ $np ], [ '*np' ] );
    my $np2 = \$num;
    print Data::Dumper->Dump( [ $np2 ], [ '*np2' ] );
    print Data::Dumper->Dump( [ $np ], [ '*np' ] );
    $$np++;
    $func->();
}
```

Which outputs this:

```
101
$np = \101;
$num = 1;
$np = \101;
$np2 = \1;
$np = \101;
102
$num = 2;
$np = \102;
$np2 = \2;
$np = \102;
103
$num = 3;
$np = \103;
$np2 = \3;
$np = \103;
104
```

Thus, inside the loop, the symbol `$num` simply does not refer to the memory pointed to by `$np`, but instead at the memory pointed to by `$np2`.